# issue trying to get a div and clone it via jquery

Tags: php, jquery, getelementbyid

I'm pretty new to web programming so, making a logic for a web-page, I made a mistake and now I'm in trouble.

I named some divs like "Dv_1.2.1.3" (without knowing the problems linked to using the dot) and I have issues trying to clone (via jquery called by button) some of these.

The button id contains the id of the div I want to clone, so, my logic is:
1) extract the id of the div;
2) get the div and clone it (giving a new id).

I'm stuck with getting the div because of the dots in the id.

The below code is what I've done so far:

```
$('.CloneDiv').click(function () {
    var SplittedId = (this.id).split('_');
    if (SplittedId[0]=='Clone'){
        alert('SplittedId 1 =' + SplittedId[1]);

        //Modify id to use it to find the div to clone
        var UsableId = SplittedId[1].replace(/\./g, '\\\\.');
        alert('UsableId =' + UsableId);
        //Count existing elements
        var ClonedNum = $('#' + 'Dv_' + UsableId + '_').length;
        ClonedNum++;
        var OrigElem = $('#' + 'Dv_' + UsableId).length;
        alert('OrigElem =' + OrigElem); //THIS IS 0
        //NO ELEMENTS FOUND BUT THE ELEMENT EXISTS
        //Clone the element and give new id
        var ClonedElem = $('#' + 'Dv_' + UsableId).clone().attr('id', function( i, val ) {
                                                                return val + '_' + ClonedNum;
                                                                });
        ClonedElem.find("input").val("");

        if (ClonedNum > 1){
            ClonedNum--;
            var AnteId = '#' + 'Dv_' + UsableId + '_' + ClonedNum;
            alert(AnteId);
            $(AnteId).after(ClonedElem);
        }else{
            var AnteId = '#' + 'Dv_' + UsableId;
            alert('AnteId = ' + AnteId);
            $(AnteId).after(ClonedElem);
        };


    }else if(SplittedId[0]=='Del'){
        alert(SplittedId[0]);
        alert('Del');
    }else{
        //error
    };
});
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? What is it not doing? If ithe code had comments I might not have felt the need to ask.

Comment: Might these help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape , Polyfill: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape/blob/master/css.escape.js

Comment: @thinsoldier You're right. I missed the malfunction. I've updated ;)

Comment: @thinsoldier YES! I solved using css.scape. Post it as answer and I'll accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might these help: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape , Polyfill: github.com/mathiasbynens/CSS.escape/blob/master/css.escape.j‌​s